# How to deserialize JSON-LD from ApiPlatform with PHP

Tags: symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

I've successfully built an API for my system with ApiPlatform. Thanks to the developers it's an excellent system. I can send it requests in JSON-LD format, and it returns its responses in JSON-LD as well.

I understand the benefits of using JSON-LD, but I feel like I am missing a big piece of the puzzle. How to deserialize to PHP objects, using the embedded JSON-LD context, in my Symfony based PHP client that is to consume the API.

Say I have the following response from my API

```
{
  "@context": "/contexts/CallbackRequest",
  "@id": "/callback-requests/72",
  "@type": "CallbackRequest",
  "id": 72,
  "created": "2017-09-22T08:07:25+02:00",
  "customer": {
    "@id": "/customers/13",
    "@type": "Customer",
    "id": 13,
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName": "Bloggs",
    "email": "joe@bloggs.com",
    "mobilePhone": "123456789"
  }
}
```

Now there is enough information available in here to deserialize to the 2 PHP objects `CallbackRequest` with nested object `Customer` thanks to the JSON-LD @context and @type data.

I have written my own denormalizer, but I have to tell the serializer what kind of object I want to deserialize to first, but I can't extract this from the JSON-LD without normalizing it first.

I have searched around a lot, looking for anyone who has made a JSON-LD normalizer/denormalizer for the Symfony serializer but have found nothing (except for this functionality inside the API Platform package itself).

Can anybody provide me any pointers, either to a JSON-LD denormalizer package that I can implement, or any suggestions on how to implement the Symfony serializer to denormalize JSON-LD without knowing what object it is supposed to contain in advance.

Comment: You share your entities between your server and your client? As you pointed out, API Platform provides a JSON-LD normalizer able to normalize and denormalize documents to PHP classes. It's not a common use case (the raw JSON-LD is often manipulated directly client-side but it should be doable with https://github.com/digitalbazaar/php-json-ld / https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld.js).

Comment: Yes, I share my entities between the client and server. I will investigate these packages. Might it be possible to extract the JSON-LD normalizer from ApiPlatform in to a standalone package? This would ensure compatibility on (de)normalizing on both client and server?? Thanks Kévin.

Comment: @Benr77 Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: 0

I'm dealing with a messy database migration, and was hoping to use API Platform to assist with the migration. The old data would serve JSON-LD from ApiPlatform, and the new code would read it, ideally serializing it to the Doctrine objects and saving it in the new database.

But having a really difficult time figuring out a generalized solution to page through the JSON-LD responses and map the response to the new entities. Is there a way for API Platform to read the JSON-LD response and page through it?